# 4 triangles of different sizes aligned in the same way

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I require 4 triangles of different sizes aligned in the same way as they are in my my code, but with the parameters I state below:

I want to draw a set of triangles. There should be 4 triangles with sides of the lengths 20, 40, 60 and 80, placed diagonally, with each triangle having the same distance in-between.

I have looked into the math docs to change the sizes in a loop but I am quite new, sorry if this is a lame question and thank you for any help provided.

```
from turtle import *
number_of_shapes = 4
for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    # Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(1, 4):
        forward(60)
        left(120)
    # Move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    left(120)
    forward(80)
    right(120)
    forward(80)
    pendown()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the parts and pieces you need for this, if not too many parts.  You simply need to set the size of the side of the triangle based on `shape` and a constant:

```
from turtle import *

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4

for shape in range(1, NUMBER_OF_SHAPES + 1):
    # Draw a Triangle
    for sides in range(3):
        forward(20 * shape)
        left(120)

    # Move forward to start position of next triangle
    penup()
    left(60)
    forward(20 * shape + 20)
    right(60)
    pendown()

done()
```

And simplify your logic for getting from one triangle to the next.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve. We use the values and the constant shape to achieve the size of the gap in between the triangles, is that right. So if I wanted a gap of 10, would I change the values as + 10 instead of + 20?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
from turtle import *

setheading(240)
for n in [20,40,60,80]:
    for _ in range(3):
        left(120)
        forward(n)
    penup()
    forward(30+n)
    pendown()
```

[image: Triangle]

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but both the OP's code and question specifically reflect ***placed diagonally***.